# Silverlight MEF to download dynamic .xap file

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have one question.I am using package catalog to download daynamic .xap file.

The size of .XAP is 4 MB.

What will happen

•When user clicks and opens my site
•XAP file will be downloade to the client
•Client works on my site and close the browser
•next time, again logs in.
•WILL XAP file downloaded again or not ? Or Client will use from cache?

I am expecting new release of my silverlight application at every three month after first release.

•Now, I have released new version
•Client comes again and logs in
•Will XAP file be downloaded automatically again ? OR client will still see old XAP's SL content.

Basically, I am not sure that silverlight is downloaded XAP file each time or only when it finds change ?